# Как сделать, чтоб при долгом нажатии в списке RecyclerView айтем менялся?

Tags: java, android

Приложение скачивает телефонную книгу и выводит ее в `CardView` в `RecyclerView` ...

Так вот я хочу сделать стандартую функцию как во многих приложениях, чтоб `RecyclerView` реагировало на долгое нажатие и справа на карточках должен появиться `CheckBox` в котором можно отметить нужные карточки для удаления например.

Я сделал слушатель который отличает долгое нажатие от короткого, но что то совсем не могу понять по какому принципу происходит обновление этих `View` при долгом нажатии...

Подскажите куда смотреть?

Comment: http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/android-recyclerview-multiple-selections-part1.html - тут 1 часть. Достаточно подробно и наглядно, на мой взгляд

Comment: @abbath0767 Если разбираетесь, может подскажите как правильно обновить тулбар? Я по этому поводу тут вопрос задал http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/555285/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-toolbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужен не полноценный режим контекстных действий ([как рекомендованный](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/android-recyclerview-multiple-selections-part1.html) в комментарии), а чтобы просто при длинном тапе появлялись, например, чекбоксы в айтемах, то алгоритм следующий:

1. В айтеме делаешь скрытый (невидимый) элемент с чекбоксом.
2. В адаптере делаешь поле-индикатор (переменная типа `boolean`), отображать этот элемент или нет и метод, который будет устанавливать состояние этому полю.
3. В методе `onBindViewHolder()` адаптера реализуешь логику по состоянию этого поля меняющюю видимость чекбокса в айтемах
4. В слушателе при длинном тапе в адаптер устанавливаешь состояние "отображать чекбоксы" методом из п.2 и обновляешь список, тут же выводишь какой-то *Bottom Bar* с действиями на отмеченных элементах.
5. При нажатии кнопки "Подтвердить действие с выбранными айтемами" (например, "удалить") -выполняешь действие и повторяешь п.4 , установив состояние "не отображать чекбоксы"
6. Метод `getChecked()` вернет отмеченные в списке позиции для дальнейшей обработки

Примерный код адаптера:

```
private class SomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SomeAdapter.ViewHolder> {

 boolean isShow;
 boolean[] checked;

 public SomeAdapter (ArrayList<String> data) {

    ...

    checked = new boolean[data.size()];
}

 ...

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

     ...

     holder.mCheckBox.setVisibility(isShow ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
     if (isShow) holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(checked[position]);
     holder.mCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           checked[position] = !checked[position];
        }
     });
   }

   public boolean[] getChecked(){
    return checked;

   public void isShowCheckbox (boolean show){

      isShow = show;
      if (isShow) Arrays.fill(checked, false); //сбрасываем для нового использования
      notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

в слушателе длинного тапа:

```
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        adapter.isShowCheckbox(true);
}
```

Comment: Да, но в таком случае мне все равно нужно как то менять тул бар и добавлять туда кнопку `action` ... Чтоб в режиме выбора она появлялась, а в обычном режиме ее не видно... А по вашему примеру я так понимаю, что эта кнопка должна всегда висеть в активити все зависимости от того в каком режиме сейчас находиться активити... Не совсем удобно

Comment: В пункте 4 об этом сказано. Нет никакой необходимости держать какую то кнопку постоянно видимой. При отработке длинного тапа вы можете делать любые действия - показывать или скрывать кнопки (как отельные, так и в Toolbar-е) , вывести всплывающий [Bottombar](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html#) с действиями для выделенных элементов и прочее

Comment: Все гениальное просто)) пол дня вчера разбирался с той статьей из комментария, так как подумал, что этот подход мне больше подойдет. Оказалось, что ваш совет работает намного проще, понятнее и быстрее в имплементации. Спасибо!)

Comment: А может вы знаете как вот на этот вопрос ответить http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556021/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-bottombar