# Как обновить ToolBar?

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, toolbar

Как правильно сделать, а то я тут что то накрутил))  Мне нужно сделать возможность выбирать несколько элементов в `RecyclerView` ...

Я следую [этому примеру](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/android-recyclerview-multiple-selections-part1.html)

При длительном нажатии на элемент списка, тулбар должен поменяться(должны добавиться соответствующие кнопки действий). В примере описан метод при котором меняется меню в тулбаре. На действующем меню вызывается метод `clear()` и следом инфлейтится новое меню с новыми кнопками. Файлы меню мы можем составить какие нужно.

Но вопрос вот в чем,  я не использую файлы меню так как мне нужно, чтоб в тулбаре по середине отображался логотип, для этого я в тулбаре создал контейнер `RelativeLayout` и разместил там элементы так как требовалось(не знаю насколько правильный подход, но так сделал)

И теперь получается у меня есть тулбар который при длительном клике на элементе списка должен поменяться... Я создал еще один `XML Toolbar` который должен заместить в макете предыдущий(не уверен, что это верно)...

Может как то динамически в `RelativeLayout` самого `Toolbar` как то добавлять новые элементы? То есть не заменять один на другой, а как бы дополнять новыми, а когда пользователь возвращается в обычный режим, то удалять их приводя тулбар в исходное положение.

Вот `XML` активити в котором это все распологается

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.ActivityFriendsInbox">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/tool_bar_left_padding" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/background_light"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/background_light"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/background_light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/pager"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

И вот сам `ToolBar`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/tool_bar_left_padding"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/color_grew_toolbar"
android:elevation="2dp"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="65dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/main_logo"
        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Как правильно сделать?

Comment: а каким образом файлы меню конфликтуют с релейтив лейаутов в тулбаре?

Comment: @xkor они не конфликтуют. Я делаю так, в обработчике длинного нажатия для теста пробую найти макет тулбара (опиональный который с доп. кнопками) и методом `setActionBar()` установить новый макет. Ожидаю, что при длинном тапе тулбар поменяется с текущего на опиональный, но ничего не меняется... Длинный тап обрабатывается, тулбар не меняется

Comment: Вообще то что вы пытаетесь сделать очень похоже на Action Mode - стандартную опцию туллбара когда повер него появляется панель действий похожая на тулбар с вариантами действий. Запускается через метод [startSupportActionMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#startSupportActionMode(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode.Callback))